# Is this a well formed multipart/form-data request?

Tags: http, multipartform-data

Can a boundary marker come at the end of the previous field data? Note that I have removed the much of the body of the XML data for brevity. The boundry marker in question is the one immediately after the  closing tag of the XML - is it valid to have a boundary marker there or should it be on the next line by itself?

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5466
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------9042941111365854226
------------9042941111365854226
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><srvhandle>...</srvhandle>------------9042941111365854226
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="objname"

auditevent
------------9042941111365854226--
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not valid as far as I can tell.

The boundary between body parts MUST begin with a `CRLF` pair. In this case, you're missing the `CRLF` in the `encapsulation`. (See below). You are **also** missing the extra `CRLF` (i.e. a blank line) that marks the end of the outer headers.

#### MIME Syntax

(Multipart/form-data follows the rules of MIME data)

This is an excerpt of what the structure of a multi-part message body looks like according to RFC 2046. (BNF syntax, somewhat simplified.)

```
multipart-body := [preamble CRLF]
                  dash-boundary CRLF
                  body-part *encapsulation
                  close-delimiter
                  [CRLF epilogue]

dash-boundary := "--" boundary

body-part := MIME-part-headers [CRLF *OCTET]

encapsulation := delimiter
                 CRLF body-part

delimiter := CRLF dash-boundary

close-delimiter := delimiter "--"
```

#### References

- [RFC 2388 Returning Values from Forms:  multipart/form-data](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2388)
- [RFC 5322 Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)
- [RFC 2045 (MIME) Part One: Format of Internet Message Bodies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)
- [RFC 2046 (MIME) Part Two: Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not valid.  MIME boundaries are always preceeded by a `CRLF`. You are missing that `CRLF` in front of the first two boundaries, but not on the last boundary.  It needs to look like this instead:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 5466
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------9042941111365854226

------------9042941111365854226
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xml"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><srvhandle>...</srvhandle>
------------9042941111365854226
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="objname"

auditevent
------------9042941111365854226--
```

Comment: Remy - thanks for your response. I am going to mark Nisse's response as the answer since he included links to references that support this answer.

Comment: Not exactly: RFC 2046 states the boundary must always starts at the start of the line. This is important for the first boundary occurrence. In your exemple, the empty line after the content type header, could be removed. The RFC also states what’s before the first boundary and after the last boundary, is to be ignored, so that’s not an error neither, but still important to know for receivers.

Comment: @Hibou57 "*In your exemple, the empty line after the content type header, could be removed.*" - no, it can't, because that empty line is actually the separator between the HTTP headers and HTTP body, so it must be present. The opening boundary is on the 1st line of the HTTP body. "*The RFC also states what’s before the first boundary and after the last boundary, is to be ignored*" - yes, within the HTTP body, but that does not apply in my example as there is nothing before the opening boundary or after the final closing boundary.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, oops, you are right, sorry. I had the message body alone in mind when I wrote it and indeed, you were talking about the HTTP header and body.